# Get XML data by name value and only one item's childrens

Tags: php, xml, xpath, multidimensional-array

i have this [XML](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=24214952,24214944,24214591) and this function that get the XML data and put it in an array.

```
function esummary_query($db, $id) { 
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
      'http'=>array(
        'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11'
       )
    ));

    $xml = file_get_contents('http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=' . $db . '&id=' . $id, FALSE, $context);

    $xml_file = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $results2 = array();
      $c=0;
    foreach ( $xml_file->DocSum as $items ) {
        $results2[$c]['id'] = $items->Id;
        $authors = $xml_file->xpath("//Item[@Name='Author']");
        foreach ($authors as $author) {
            $results2[$c]['authors'][] = $author;
        }
          $c++;
    }
    return $results2;
}
```

But this get all items with name="Author" each time that read a DocSum. I know this occurs because i am selecting all items with name="authors" wherever they are, but after many attemps, i can't fix it.

Somebody can help me? Thanks!

Comment: try removing the "//" in the xpath.

Comment: if a remove // or if i put / it doesn't work, the array dont save any author name.

Comment: I think i finally understand what you are looking for; use "Item/Item[@Name='Author']" for your xpath. (sorry, my php is so rusty it flakes)

Comment: that doesn't work, too. I don't know why, but only gets the data if I put //, of all the other ways I've tried, the array is empty, as if the path is not correct.

Comment: if my guess about php is correct than change "$authors = $xml_file->xpath("//Item[@Name='Author']");" into " $authors = $items->xpath("Item/Item[@Name='Author']");"

Comment: it works! Thansk, i have been a lot of time to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Why not build an array like this:

```
$results2[id] = Array("Author1", "Author2", "Author3");
```

with this code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

foreach ($xml->DocSum as $doc) {
$temp = Array();
$authors = $doc->xpath("//Item[@Name='Author']");
foreach ($authors as $a) $temp[] = (string)$a;
$results2[(string)$doc->Id] = $temp;
}
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/syGINn

Comment: This put all author's in the same id, and i want to put each authors within their id. Moreover, the function isnt complete, it will have more keys. But is a good idea to use id in first level array, thanks!

Comment: @Genethic you're right, I thought it would return the authors for one DocSum only...